# bash ignores shebang when running file passed as argument

Tags: bash, shebang

How can I have bash respect the shebang when passing a file as an argument?

eg:
*hello.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Hello Python")
```

When passed to bash:

```
$ bash hello.py
hello.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `"Hello Python"'
hello.py: line 2: `print("Hello Python")'
```

In the environment I’m using I unfortunately can’t execute hello.py directly, it has to be done by supplying args to bash.

Comment: Of course Bash ignores it, it's a comment; shebangs are meant for the kernel. You want to run `/usr/bin/env python hello.py`, right? Just want to make sure cause I could also imagine having Bash error with a more descriptive error message is another option.

Comment: `bash SOMEFILE` executes _SOMEFILE_ as a bash script.  This is described in the bash man page. You could write `bash -c ./hello.py` to force the #! line being considered (provided that _hello.py_ is executable), but this would create one additional (unnecessary) child process, as you could run it equally well simply by `./hello.py`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't run scripts with an explicit interpreter. Always execute them by just typing the script name; that way the interpreter listed in the shebang will be used.

```
$ ./hello.py
```

This will require that the script is executable so make sure to do that if you haven't already.

```
$ chmod +x hello.py
```

If you have to run `bash` then use `-c` to pass a full command and stop it from trying to read it as a bash script:

```
$ bash -c './hello.py'
```

Comment: If I had interactive access I would, but in the environment I’m using I can only pass args to bash. I was hoping to find some combination that would trigger bash to select the shebang interpreter but perhaps this isn’t possible?